How to add row annotation to complex heatmap in r
I am working on plotting a complex heatmap and need to include both column and row annotations in the figure's legend.
I would like to cut the row dendrogram and assign colors to the clusters obtained from the dendrogram. Additionally, I want to include cluster labels in the annotation. While I am using anno_simple() to add row cluster labels, I am currently able to display only the colors in the figure, not the cluster numbers (labels).
Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this? Thank you!

# generate data for plot
data <- matrix(rnorm(300), nrow = 50, ncol = 6)
rownames(data) <- paste0("Gene_", 1:50)
colnames(data) <- paste0("Study_", 1:6)


# create study annotation (column annotation)
study.df <- data.frame(sample = colnames(data), group = c(rep("group1", 3), rep("group2", 3) ))
study_color <- c("group1" = "red", "group2" = "blue" )
col_annot <- HeatmapAnnotation(group = study.df$group,
                               col = list(group = study_color))
col_fun = colorRamp2(c(-4, 0, 4), c("darkgreen", "white", "darkred")) #


# plot the heatmap
heatmap2 <- Heatmap(data,
                    name = "lFC",
                    use_raster = FALSE,
                    col = col_fun,
                    show_row_names = FALSE,
                    show_row_dend = TRUE,
                    top_annotation = col_annot)
heatmap2


# cluster the row dendeogram
ht = draw(heatmap2)
dend <- row_dend(ht) 
row_hclust <- as.hclust(dend) # create an hclust object

clusters <- cutree(row_hclust, k = 4) # cut the dendeogram in 4 clusters

# row annotation
unique_clusters <- unique(clusters)
cluster_colors <- setNames(rainbow(length(unique_clusters)), unique_clusters)
row_annot <- rowAnnotation(Cluster = anno_simple(clusters, col = cluster_colors))

# add row annotation to the heatmap
heatmap2 <- Heatmap(data, name = "lFC",
                    show_row_names = F,
                    show_row_dend = T,
                    col = col_fun,
                    row_dend_width = unit(10, "cm"),
                    top_annotation = col_annot,
                    left_annotation = row_annot)
draw(heatmap2)

I need to add a legend for row annotation (cluster1, cluster2, ...) on right side of the heatmap.
heatmap
